# swift: How can I save a photo to the Photos app on OSX/macOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have an NSImage object and I want to save it to the Photos App on OSX/macOS.

I guess I'm looking for the equivalent of the **UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum** function for OSX/macOS. What is it?